# How can i configure in web.xml file to skip a class to not to under go ContainerRequestFilters?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have configured filter for my Jersey Webservices this way

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.services.admin</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>com.util.SessionCheckFilter</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Which is forcing every class present under package com.services.admin; to under go com.util.SessionCheckFilter check

Where inside SessionCheckFilter class i have this logic

```
public class SessionCheckFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter { 
@Context HttpServletRequest req ;
    @Override 
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest cr) {
     HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if(session==null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(401); // Throw new UnAuthorized 
            return cr;  
        }
        else {
            return cr;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is can i skip one class named AdminLogin.java to not to under go the  SessionCheckFilter check ??

```
package com.services.admin;
@Path("/adminlogin")
public class AdminLogin {
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/text")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String adminLogin(   
            @QueryParam(value="password")String password,
            @QueryParam(value="admin_mobile")String admin_mobile,@Context HttpServletRequest hsr)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar to what you're looking for with a custom annotation.

If you inject `ResourceInfo` into your filter, you can look for annotations defined on the resource at either the class or method level.

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

In your case, you'd simply bypass your filter logic if the annotation `MyIgnoreAnnotation` is present.

```
if(resource.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyIgnoreAnnotation.class))
    return;
```

And finally the annotation. You should rename it something meaningful.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyIgnoreAnnotation {
}
```

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for throwing the light for what to look for .  When i did the below 
if(resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotationsByType(MyIgnoreAnnotation.class).length != 0) {} 

 I am getting Compilation error  and what should be present in place of MyIgnoreAnnotation.class Could you please help

Comment: You need to create an annotation, `MyIgnoreAnnotation` is just a placeholder. Create the annotation class and annotate your `AdminLogic` class with it. I've added a sample above.